# Current transformer design guideline

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, current-measurement

I want to design current transformers with two secondary windings (one for control loop and another for monitoring.) It will be used in DC-DC converter. What are the guidelines to be followed for the current transformer core selection? Current measuring is in the range of 17A peak current with duty cycle less than 50%.

Comment: What do you mean monitoring? Should the other winding be used as a normal current transformer (requires burden resistor)? Why can't the converter's current sense be filtered/buffered as a DC output? What switching frequency and edge rate?

Comment: Monitoring means bringing out through buffer to data logging. one winding output will be used in the control loop and the other for monitoring. User requirement is to have a separate current sensing for control loop. The switching frequency is 125 KHz.

Comment: It sounds like the easiest solution is use two current transformers (primaries wired in series). You didn't mention edge rate so I don't know if the added leakage inductance will be a problem.